# Save as feature using textfields

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, uitableview, uitextfield

In my app there are textfields in a different view and are all part of one array but there are several arrays with different textfield values. For example,there may be a 2 in the first textfield and a 5 in the second in one array but then a 6 in the first textfield and a 4 in the second in another array. When you click the saveAs button it will take you to the NameSaveAsView where there's another textfield. This textfield will give a name to that array so that when you go into the OpenShiftView you see each name in a tableview cell and can load up the array you want. This is the code I've got so far which I thought should of worked but whenever I test it it works fine except the OpenShiftView just loads up with empty cells. What is wrong with my code? Thanks for any help.

```
//
//  NameSaveAsViewController.m
//  ShiftCalculator
//
//  Created by John on 21/11/2013.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 John. All rights reserved.
//

#import "NameSaveAsViewController.h"

@implementation NameSaveAsViewController
@synthesize saveAsText, normalWage, overtimeWage, mondayNormalTime, mondayOverTime,   
tuesdayNormalTime, tuesdayOverTime, wednesdayNormalTime, wednesdayOverTime, 
thursdayNormalTime, thursdayOverTime, fridayNormalTime, fridayOverTime,   
saturdayNormalTime, saturdayOverTime, sundayNormalTime, sundayOverTime, bonusMoney,  
tArray, string5, mArray;


-(void)viewDidLoad {

[super viewDidLoad];

UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self   
action:@selector(dismissKeyboard:)];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap];




}

- (void)dismissKeyboard:(id)sender
{
if ([saveAsText isEditing]) {
    [saveAsText resignFirstResponder];
}
}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
saveAsText.placeholder = @"Shift Name";
NSString *string5 = saveAsText.text;

}

- (void)saveAs:(id)sender
{
[mArray addObject:string5];
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:mArray forKey:@"saveArray"];

NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:strings forKey:@"saveArray2"];
 }
 @end

//
//  OpenShiftViewController.m
//  ShiftCalculator
//
//  Created by John on 21/11/2013.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 John. All rights reserved.
//

#import "OpenShiftViewController.h"


@implementation OpenShiftViewController
@synthesize textFields, arr, myMutableArray, myDictionary, defaults;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
myDictionary = [defaults dictionaryRepresentation];
self.arr = [defaults arrayForKey:@"saveArray"];

}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{

return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return arr.count;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath    
*)indexPath
{

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (!cell) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle    
reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

}

cell.textLabel.text = [arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


return cell;
}
@end
```

Comment: I really can't understand what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Can't really tell without seeing the header file for `OpenShiftViewController`, but it looks like you are declaring a local variable `arr` masking an instance variable, also called `arr`. What happens if you change the line in `-viewDidLoad` to `self.arr = [defaults arrayForKey:@"saveArray"];` Also you are assigning the same value to two label in the same cell, which seems strange, and the end of `viewDidLoad` is clearly unfinished, since it's calling an empty method

Comment: I am basically trying to create a save as feature with the textfields.

Answer (score 0):

You need to figure out the concept of local variables.  The 'arr' you define in viewDidLoad and the 'mArray' in textFieldDidEndEditing only exist in those methods.  You seem to have other variables with the same names as instance variables but those aren't the same ones.

Together, those problems are almost certainly responsible for the symptoms you're seeing.  Try using your instance variables instead of creating local ones.

Comment: If you update your question with the new code maybe someone could figure out what else is wrong.

Comment: You're still creating local variables that mask the instance ones.  In the new code, it's `NSString *string5 = saveAsText.text;`.  That's not the same `string5` that you're using in the `saveAs:` method.